# Google Drive SDK - How to define my own MIME Type?

Tags: google-drive-api

I am writing a crawler app and I was trying to have my own iconLink and assign my app to open my crawler docs (xml) automatically.

I tried to define my own MIME-Type and assign it to my app. I've tried a few options with no real success. I am using the js API.

**Option 1 - "application/crawler" as Mime-Type**

- The app iconLink is fixed on
  //ssl.gstatic.com/docs/doclist/images/icon_10_generic_list.png. and I
  can not change it.
- I can not make my app as a default for this    Mime-Type

**Option 2 - "application/vnd.google-apps.drive-sdk.XXXX" as Mime-Type**

Zoho Writer is using this style

> "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.drive-sdk.457660898219"

I tried it, however, when I use Google API Console to assign this MIME-Type with my app I get an error saying:

> MIME types beginning with "application/vnd.google-apps." are reserved
>   for internal use

**Option 3 - "text/xml" as Mime-Type**

Other apps using the "text/xml" Mime-Type becoming the default for opening my document.

I could not manage to fix it just bu using 'crawler' extension to my files.

Comment: #1 should work fine. Could you clarify why exactly it isn't working for you?

Comment: thanks. #1 works fine now. Not sure what the problem was.